# CALCULATING RATE OF CHANGE IN SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, calculation

I am executing a stored procedure in SQL using the following code

```html
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
  @sTags = N'COL_NAME1,COL_NAME2,COL_NAME3',
  @iUTCAdjustment = 8,
  @sPastUnits = N'30',
  @iTimeInterval = 15

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Which Yields me an output as below

```html
LT                         UTC                         COL_NAME1     COL_NAME2    COL_NAME3
2019-09-01 09:15:00.0000000 2019-09-01 01:15:00.0000000 6.4093919     7.5931386    7.8139451
2019-09-01 09:30:00.0000000 2019-09-01 01:30:00.0000000 6.4053431     6.9238622    7.7541301
2019-09-01 09:45:00.0000000 2019-09-01 01:45:00.0000000 6.4012942     7.2387368    6.9653121
2019-09-01 10:00:00.0000000 2019-09-01 02:00:00.0000000 6.3972454     7.1358283    7.1836296
```

I Wish to add a new column whose value is the rate of change of COL_NAME1. The time interval is always fixed,15 minutes. So the denominator can be 15.

Rate of change = [COL_NAME1(n)-COL_NAME1(n-1)]/15.

how do i modify my above code to get my expected output.

Comment: can't you just modify the stored procedure to return the additional column that you want ?

Comment: I am not the Store Procedure developer. I am the end user who makes use of the Data from the store procedure as input to my application. Hence not very familiar to modify the store procedure.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table, insert the results, and do the manipulations:

```
create table t (
    LT ?,
    UTC ?,
    COL_NAME1 ?,
    COL_NAME2 ?,
    COL_NAME3 ?
);
```

The types need to match the return types from the stored procedure, so I've used `?`:

```
insert into t
    exec . . . ;  -- your exec statement here
```

Then you can manipulate the result table with the calculation you want.

Comment: I need to work within the same table. I have a different application which reads this SQL table. Creating a new table means, new linking needs to be done. Hence without creating a new table, i am looking to add a new column by adding few extra lines to the existing code.

Comment: @SairamSEKARAN . . . What table?  You just have a result set returned by a stored procedure.  If you need to change the result set, you need to change the stored procedure.

Comment: Understand. I will check with the Stored Procedure developer on how to do that. Thanks Gorden. But if there is alternative methods where i don't need to modify the stored procedure, but the SQL code that returns the result set do help out. Thanks